# How should I set up my wireless-N FIOS router?

Tags: wireless-networking, fios

It’s in my basement, and I only get wireless coverage in the basement and on the main floor but not on the second floor. It’s a wireless [GigE N Actiontec MI424WR](http://www.actiontec.com/214.html) router and I’m thinking of which high gain antenna is best since you can't really bridge their routers.

My questions are:

1. How can I get coverage to the rest of my house? Should I get a high-gain antenna? Or can I add an AP for it, connected via wired Ethernet, and just run one Ethernet cable to where I need it for the rest of the house?
2. My PS3 is the only non 801.11n compatible device I have, so I’m not running performance 801.11n-only mode since the PS3 is not compatible. But if I change it to performance 801.11n-only mode, will my wired connections only accept 801.11n or is there a way I can have the wired be totally adaptable while only my wireless is 801.11n only?

Comment: Is the router really **required** to be in the basement, or can you move it to a higher floor? In my house, the router works with any coax outlet, and I moved it from room to room until I found a spot I liked.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is subjective. You just have to try one option and see if it works. I'd say set up an AP, but that's just my opinion, not a solution that's proven to work in that case.

On the second question, "N" stands for IEEE 802.11n, which is a Wi-Fi standard. Wired connections aren't affected by this at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need more coverage vertically, try orienting the MI424WR's existing omnidirectional dipole antennas horizontally. A dipole antenna radiates energy the best out the "sides" of the stick, and not as well out the "top and bottom ends" of the stick.

Omnidirectional antennas aren't great for covering a multistory house, because they're only omnidirectional in a 2D disc, not in a 3D sphere (an antenna with a perfectly even spherical coverage pattern would be called an "isotropic" antenna). So if you orient the sticks horizontally to get better coverage vertically, they'll also be shooting lots of energy at the basement floor.  So if you get a pair of high-gain antennas, don't go for high-gain omnidirectional dipoles. But don't go for something *too* directional either, because you don't just want to cover the shaft directly above your AP, you want to cover the whole house. Consider trying something with a 90° or wider beam-width, like [this](http://www.radiolabs.com/products/antennas/2.4gig/2.4-indoor-wall-mount.php).

Overall, I'm not sure that diddling with antennas is likely to bring you all that much success. I'd recommend you go with the idea of running Ethernet cable from your MI424WR to a separate AP you could install somewhere where it provides good coverage to the areas the MI424WR doesn't reach. This would also be a good time to buy a *real* 802.11 AP, and maybe even stop using the really crappy level of 802.11n support that your MI424WR has. To future-proof yourself, get a modern high-power dual-band 802.11ac AP like the 2013 Apple AirPort Extreme (the tower-shaped one) or the ASUS RT-AC66U. I've tested several 802.11ac APs for performance, and those two are the cream of the crop.

As for your second question, 802.11n is a wireless standard, and has nothing to do with wired Ethernet. Your second AP would translate the frames from 802.11n frames to standard Ethernet frames before sending them over the Ethernet cable.

Also, don't bother with performance N-only mode. It's a very minor performance improvement, and your MI424WR's level of 802.11n (a.k.a. "wireless-N") support is so crappy (130 mbps; 2.4GHz only; requires 40MHz wide channels in 2.4GHz which stomp on Bluetooth and Wii remotes and cordless phones and baby monitors and other users of the band; would only be 65 mbps if you set it to normal 20MHz channels) that it's not worth bothering with "performance" mode. Also, on some APs, N-only mode disables G and B rates, which actually limits the range of even your 802.11n clients. For best results, leave B, G, and N all enabled, but try to replace any legacy B or G clients as soon as you can.

Comment: For clarification, the coverage of an omnidirectional antenna is similar to a doughnut. While coverage is strongest and uniform perpendicular to the orientation of the antenna (and practically non-existent directly above and below) there is three-dimensional coverage.